# subdomain routing to multiple controller issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

I have a site: www.mydomain.com where we have administrative controls hidden away from normal customer view.  I would like to only access the administrative features under a subdomain such as admin.mydomain.com.  I can ensure that any requests to an administrative feature has to have admin in the subdomain, but how can I make sure that if the admin clicks anything else on the site such as a link to "mydomain.com/about_company" that they would get off of the admin host domain, and gets set back to the regular www.mydomain.com?

From my understanding of rails routing, a subdomain can be directed to a controller, but my administrative features are split into multiple controllers.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use subdomain_fu http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu for this matter.